# Can the property of the strong finite intersection be extended to an ultrafilter?

Tags: set-theory, filters

**Definition**. Let X be an infinite set and $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$. We will say that $\mathcal{F}$ has the property of the strong finite intersection if
\begin{align*}
\forall \sigma\in[\mathcal{F}]^{<\omega}:\left|\bigcap\sigma\right|\geq\omega
\end{align*}

If $\mathcal{F}$ has the property of the strong finite intersection it is clear that the filter generated by $\mathcal{F}$ also has that property.

If $\mathcal{U}$ is any ultrafilter that extends to $\mathcal{F}$, does $\mathcal{U}$ also have such property?

Comment: Any ultrafilter extends $\mathcal F=\{X\}$, and this $\mathcal F$ has the strong fip. But (as Asaf answered using a principal ultrafilter) not every ultrafilter has the strong fip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no.

Suppose that $X=\omega\cup\{\omega\}$ and $\cal F$ is the filter generated by cofinite subsets of $\omega$ on $X$. Then $\cal F$ has an extension to a principal ultrafilter by adding $\{\omega\}$ to $\cal F$.

And clearly, a principal ultrafilter does not have the strong finite intersection property.

Comment: I guess you could have taken any infinite $X$ and $\mathcal F=\{X\}$ and extend that to any principal filter. Your answer also helped me think about it and realize that for an ultrafilter to fail the strong fip it has to be a principal filter (generated by a singleton).